# Generating Individual Shapes from Points with values

Tags: python, shapely

I have this shapefile of points, categorized in 8 colors.

[image]

what i want to do, using python and shapely is, for each category create a shapefile (fill polygon), but when i try this, i get this result.
(The points around the polygon i made on photo editor to ilustrate)

[image]

its possible to get this individuals shapes?

Comment: Try looking for concave hull